# Array keys by another arrays values

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have an array $params with the following content:

```
Array(
  0 => "array"
  1 => "arrayName" //variable
  2 => "key1" //optional&variable ie. 0 or 'foo'
  3 => "key2" //optional&variable ie. 0 or 'foo'
  //etc.
)
```

Also, I have an stdObject that contains all my variables for the page that is being requested (MVC style). 
So, I could have an array in there like this:

```
$std = new stdObject();
$std->arrayName->array('foo', 'bar');
```

Now I want the first value of the $std array. So I am using the "key1" parameter in $params and set this to '0' so it will pick the $std->arrayName[0] value ('foo'). Note that I am not using the "key2" parameter since I don't want to select $std->arrayName[key1][key2].

But what if I need the value of a nested array?

```
$std = new stdObject();
$std->arrayName->array('foo', array('bar', 'fish'));
```

I will request the $std->arrayName[1][1] value ('fish') by setting the "key1" parameter to 1 and the "key2" parameter to 1 as well. So it will select $std->arrayName[key1][key2].

But what if I have 10 arrays nested in each other? highly unlikely, but it's possible. I want to select $std->arrayName[key1][key2][key3][..][key10] to select a certain value that's located there.
For example: $std->arrayName[0][3][4][6][2][9]['foo']['bar][9][2];

So my question is: how do I select the value of a certain array (arrayName) by the values defined in another array ($params) that act as the keys for the first array (arrayName). But, the amount of keys (values in $params) is optional.

Maybe the question isn't completely understandable, so feel free to ask more information.

Comment: I have read the question twice and still have no idea what it is about. You may be better had modified the examples so they have similar key names, since it is not obvious how `key_name_1` is related to `foo`

Comment: @zerkms I changed the question. Is it better to understand?

Comment: nope. Personally I still don't see any connection between `fish` and `key1`

Comment: fish = value, key1 = key. Where that key1 is a variable value, that could be set to 0, 1, 2, 'foo' or 'bar' just to select a certain value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop the key array and assign each level to a variable, until you reach the end when you should have the value you want.

Something like this (untested, no error checking):

```
function array_value_at ($array, $keys) {
  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $array = $array[$key];
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Comment: @Jelmer This is relatively simple, although it would be a good idea if you add at least an `isset()` check in there to make sure you don't trigger a load of errors when the keys array references something that doesn't exist. Where this sort of thing starts to get interesting is when you want to get a *reference* to the item described by the keys array, you have to be very careful not to modify the input array.

Comment: Yep I know ;) I kept that part away from the question for easier understanding :) thanks for the tip though. Will be helpful for a lot of others.